# Write contents of each php array on a new line in a text file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, newline, implode

I have used a while loop to fetch rows from a database and collect them in an array.

Now what I want to achieve is that on each iteration of this loop, the elements of the array should be written on a new line in a text file

I've tried `implode` but it's not working. I am probably using it in a completely wrong way.
Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT hist FROM loch ;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$file = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/ip.txt";
fopen($file,'a');

$output=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{

        $instr1 = implode("\n", $row);
        file_put_contents($file, $instr1, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);   
}
```

I want the output to look like this -

```
1 2 10 5
1 2 10
```

But what I am getting is this -

```
1 2 10 51 2 10
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PHP_EOL` to add a new line like so:

```
file_put_contents($file, $instr1 . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: You could also concatenate a new line break after your implode if you so desired. I like the verbosity of a dedicated constant like `PHP_EOL` but sometimes it's a little more reasonable to use `\n` as in `$instr1."\n"` especially when you have to place a number of line breaks in a statement.